# How should I retrieve files from GridFs? gfs.files.find() does not work and loading forever

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I am trying to display all the files, so I want to retrieve all the files first as arrays, so that I can mapping on frontend part.

I tried to solve this issue by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f5Q9wDePzY&t=1966s.
Seems like there has been a lot of update on GridFs since when the video was made. I tried all the solutions on the reply of the video above, and solutions on stackoverflow too. None of them worked unfortunately.

So this is the part showing what modules I use, and how I connect to MongoDB, how to initilize GFS, and so on.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const {GridFsStorage} = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto')

require('dotenv').config();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//connecting MongoDB
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGOOSE_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });


//Initialize GridFS
let gfs;
conn.once('open', () => {
  console.log('GridFS initialized!')
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');  
  
});

// Create storage engine for Multer
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.MONGOOSE_URI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
          
          

        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          metadata:{
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            phone: req.body.phone
          }
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  
}});
```

This is the route to retrieve the files.

```
//retreiving the datas
app.get('/data', (req, res)=>{
  
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      })
    } 
    return res.json(files);
  });
})
```

The problem is on the 'GET' route. When I do 'GET' request, gfs.files.find() not working. It is loading infinitely. It does not get to next line. So when I tried gfs.find(), it says 'gfs.find() is not a function'. I wonder how to solve this issue.

Comment: How many files/how much data are you dealing with here?

Comment: @user20042973 Not even much I don't think the max will be over even 50 files. Each file will be just image files. And some datas will be stored as metadata. So the number of files would not be a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

I also having this issue. I followed the same youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f5Q9wDePzY and got stuck for days. Then I tried this code below and then it worked for me. IDK what happened there. Hope this will work for you.

```
app.get("/files", async (req, res) => {
    await gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).json({ err });
    console.log({files});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got Stuck on this problem for hours, because the tutorial was from 5years ago and a lot of changes has been made since then. Here is the solution that I used and it worked, I hope it works well for you too

```
app.get("/files", async (req, res) => {
   try {
       let files = await gfs.files.find().toArray();
       res.json({files})
   } catch (err) {
       res.json({err})
   }
});
```